# Why do I have this very weird reflections?

Tags: materials, lighting, reflection

Why are those real weird reflection on the edge of the the driver appear. I didn't use any kind of glossy or metallic material on it. How do I fix it? Thank you in advance[image]
I'll include blender file

[image]

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve definitely seen speakers with a ring of glossier material in that position, on the edge of the mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the material named `Material.003` , you have a Principled BSDF node that has a Clearcoat value set to 1 and Clearcoat Roughness set to 0.03. This emulates a reflective layer on top of the normal Roughness value.